# Laravel login with another database

Tags: laravel

At this moment I am working on a laravel 5.6 application, but the client has asked me to login in sqlserver, I have already created a custom class that connects to sqlserver, the problem is I occupy the laravel Auth class , someone could help me connect laravel auth with my sqlserver class or gift me any ideas?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your app runs on a database separated from the one to use for authentication?

Comment: Are you trying to change the database connection dynamically?

Comment: the main database is mysql but the login users data are in slqserver

Comment: the main database is mysql but the login users data are in Ms sqlserver, i created a new class in laravel that connect with Ms sqlserver and in the controllers of the app i use Auth for get the user data for various process.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel outof the box, comes with functionality to connect with SQL server. I don't think you need to create a custom class on your own.

You might need to configure Laravel to connect to your SQL server though. Have a look at the link below for setting up Laravel for SQL server...

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database

Comment: not all aplication database is required in Ms SqlServer, only login table

Comment: There are few ways you can specify which db connection to use. See this article for details. http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections